# What is the fully qualified name of a model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have 2 different classes with name `User`, say one in `FooModule` and other as a model in `app/models/user.rb`, how do I make sure I am using the correct one?

EDIT:
`FooModule::User` would definitely give me the correct one.

What I had meant to ask was:
If `ApplicationController` includes `FooModule`, would `User` or `::User` still give me `app/models/user`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to them using their full names, FooModule::User and ::User

Generally if you just use User, it should assume you mean ::User, unless you are within FooModule.  Either way, use FooModule::User or ::User to be sure.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the module is the same name as the ActiveRecord model, ie `Foo::User` and `::Foo`. When you try to call `::Foo.new` it gives the error `undefined method \`new' for Foo:Module`.