# How to distinguish class "ClassA" from "Module::ClassA"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So my problem is that I have two classes with the same name.

One is REXML::Document, which is a third party library.

the other is an ActiveRecord model called "Document" controlled by my application.

In my controller when I do "Document.transaction" he tells me that method "transaction" doesn't exist for class "REXML::Document" but what I really want is to use my model. My model doesn't belong to a module so how can I tell ruby that he should look to the model "Document" instead of "REXML::Document" ?

Comment: I had asked a similar question, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270227/what-is-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::Document` tells Ruby to start the name lookup at the top-level as opposed to the current level.

It's similar a Unix pathname, where the `/` also functions both as a pathname component separator and as a flag to not use relative lookup.

However, if you are inside your controller, `Document` by itself should *never* refer to `REXML::Document`. It should *always* only look for `Document`, first in the current namespace, then one level up, and so forth until the top-level namespace (which is actually nothing special, it's just the `Object` class).

Unless, of course, you have `include REXML` somewhere in your code, in which case, there is an even simpler remedy than using `::Document`: just don't do that.

Comment: You're correct, it should first look for Document and only then for REXML::Document. I found the problem. We had a helper that was including "REXML" module in the body of the file outside any class or module, I believe this was making it available for any file in the rails application.
I believe I can fix this by moving the include to inside the module that needs it. However, just for future reference, what is the simpler remedy you talk about in this situation? What if my controller included REXML ? How could I reference Document over REXML::Document ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plenty of duplicated of this question I think.
The answer is, in any case, to use `::Document` although I would have thought just typing `Document` would have preferred `Document` to `REXML::Document`

Comment: I looked around and found no answer. It's kind of tricky to search around for this subject, it's very specific. For some reason the application was favoring "REXML::Document" over "Document". I found out why. However doing "::Document" wasn't fixing it.