# How do I use a model that has the same name as a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I saw this question but it didn't help: [What is the fully qualified name of a model in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270227/what-is-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)

I have this code

```
# create Stripe customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(:email => @user.email, :source => params['subscription']['token'])
stripe_subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(:customer => customer.id, :plan => @subscription.plan)
stripe = ::Stripe.new subscription: @subscription, customer_id: customer.id, plan_id: @subscription.plan, 
  stripe_subscription_id: stripe_subscription.id, last_paid: Time.now, status: stripe_subscription.status
```

Stripe is a gem, but it's also the name of my model. I tried `::Stripe.new` above, and I also tried `stripe = @subscription.build_stripe ...`. They both gave the error

> undefined method `new' for Stripe:Module

Comment: I suggest creating a namespace for your `Stripe` model to avoid any conflicts with `Stripe` module.

Comment: You cannot use same name for both. You can try renaming your model

    class CustomModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = "your_table_name_in_db"
    end

Comment: @Gerry How do I create a namespace? I tried `module MyModule;
class Stripe < ApplicationRecord` but when I try to create a new instance in the console with `MyModule::Stripe.new`, it gives `NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule`.

Comment: @Chloe Did you moved your file into `models/my_model` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A module and class of the same name cannot exist at the top-level namespace. If you actually *did* get Rails to load your `Stripe` module, your app would crash with a type error, complaining that you've tried to change the type of `Stripe` from module to class.

Comment: It's not crashing with a type error. It loads and runs until the last line in the code snippet. It does recognize `Stripe::` module like `Stripe::Customer`.

Comment: @Chloe I said **if** you actually got Rails to load your model, it would crash. Rails isn't even aware you have a model named `Stripe`. It never loads it. When Rails encounters `Stripe` in your code, it's already defined as a module, so Rails' autoloader doesn't actually go looking for your model, so your model is never even loaded. You need to rename your model or put it inside a module. I'd suggest renaming, as "Stripe" isn't a very descriptive model name. What is it, a payment? An account? A transaction? There *has* to be a better name.